# tableview not showing data from database

Tags: java, sql, database, javafx, tableview

I am unable to populate my tableview. I believe the problem is in the controller, in the way my data is being sent to the FXML file, because a system out print (see below) shows exactly what I have in my database.

Please let me know where I did a mistake. I went over all tutorials that exist on that, but nothing fits my problem.

Thanks

Main App:

```
package tableview;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/FXMLTable.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();    
}
}
```

Controller:

```
import tableview.model.Person;


public class FXMLTableController{

@FXML
public TableView<Person> tableview ;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, Number> clientIdColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn;

@FXML   
private void initialize() {
         assert tableview != null : "fx:id=\"tableview\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'UserMaster.fxml'.";
         clientIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().
                 clientIDProperty());

        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue()
                .firstNameProperty());              
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue()
                .lastNameProperty());

         buildData();

    }

private ObservableList<Person> data;


public  void buildData(){        
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Connection con = null;


        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:tableviewdb.db");

        String SQL = "Select * from INFO";            
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);  
        while(rs.next()){
            Person per = new Person();
            per.ClientID.set(rs.getInt("CLIENTID"));
            per.FirstName.set(rs.getString("FIRSTNAME"));
            per.LastName.set(rs.getString("LASTNAME"));

            data.add(per);  

        }
        tableview = new TableView<Person>();
        tableview.setItems(data);
        System.out.println(tableview.getItems().get(1).ClientID);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Error on Building Data");            
    }
   }
}
```

Model Class:

```
package tableview.model;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {
    public SimpleIntegerProperty ClientID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty FirstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty LastName = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public SimpleIntegerProperty getClientID() {
        return ClientID;
    }
    public SimpleStringProperty getFirstname() {
        return FirstName;
    }
    public SimpleStringProperty getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }
    public IntegerProperty clientIDProperty(){
        return ClientID;
    }
    public StringProperty firstNameProperty(){
        return FirstName;

    }
    public StringProperty lastNameProperty(){
        return LastName;    
    }
}
```

FXML file:
(disregard the save button for now...)

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
   <children>
      <SplitPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <items>
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="160.0">
              <items>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                     <children>
                        <TextField layoutX="93.0" layoutY="34.0" />
                        <TextField layoutX="93.0" layoutY="85.0" />
                        <Label layoutX="35.0" layoutY="39.0" text="name" />
                        <Label layoutX="35.0" layoutY="90.0" text="email" />
                        <Button layoutX="204.0" layoutY="140.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="save" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView layoutY="-2.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="598.0">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn prefWidth="302.0" text="name" />
                            <TableColumn prefWidth="295.0" text="email" />
                          </columns>
                        </TableView>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </items>
            </SplitPane>
         </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new `TableView` and setting its items, instead of setting the items on the table that the FXML file defined. Remove the

```
tableView = new TableView<Person>();
```

from the controller.

To get the `@FXML`-annotated fields in the controller to be populated with the appropriate elements from the FXML file, you need to add `fx:id` attributes to those elements:

```
<TableView fx:id="tableview" ... >
  <columns>
    <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" ... />
    ...
```

Comment: You forgot the `fx:id` attributes in your FXML file. (If you run it with assertions enabled you should see an assertion error.) See updated answer.